# AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am using grid search to tune parameters of my models (Random Forest, Linear Regression, etc.). So I save `gs` objects in `grid_searches`:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(model, params, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs,
                  verbose=verbose, scoring="mean_squared_error", refit=refit)
gs.fit(trainX,trainy)
grid_searches[key] = gs
```

Then I want to access the best estimator for each model in order to make predictions:

```
def predict(testX, testy, grid_searches):
    keys = models.keys()
    for k in keys:
        print("Predicting with %s." % k)
        yhat = grid_searches[k].best_estimator_.predict(testX)
```

The error is the following:

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'
```

So how should I make predictions using best models found by Grid Search?

Comment: You should just be able to just use `grid_searches[k].predict(testX)`. After you call `gs.fit(...)`, `gs` should have the optimized parameters (based on the search space). What happens if you try just `grid_searches[k].predict(...)`? Also, what happens if you add a line under `gs.fit(...)` with `print gs.best_estimator_`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear, from the code excerpt, how you set `refit`. Per the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html), `best_estimator_` is only available when this is `True`. If `False`, you should still be able to find the best-performing parameters from `grid_scores_`, then use them with `set_params()`.